# Train a tensorflow model minimizing the loss of several batches

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to train the weights of a model based on the sum of the loss value of several batches. However it seems that once you run the graph for each of the individual batches, the object that is returned is just a regular numpy array. So when you try and use an optimizer like GradientDescentOptimizer, it no longer has information about the variables that were used to calculate the sum of the losses, so it can't find the gradients of the weights that what help minimize the loss. Here's an example tensorflow script to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.ones([num_feature_values], tf.float32))
feature_values = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[num_feature_values])
labels  = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[1])

loss_op = some_loss_function(weights, feature_values, labels)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for batch in batches:
        feed_dict = fill_feature_values_and_labels(batch)

        #Calculates loss for one batch
        loss = sess.run(loss_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        #Adds it to total loss
        total_loss += loss

# Want to train weights to minimize total_loss, however this 
# doesn't work because the graph has already been run.
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(total_loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for step in xrange(num_steps):
        sess.run(optimizer)
```

The `total_loss` is a numpy array and thus cannot be used in the optimizer. Does anyone know a way around the problem, where I want to use information across many batches but still need the graph intact in order to preserve the fact that the `total_loss` is a function of the weights?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you optimize in any of the trainers must be a part of the graph, here what you train on is the actual realized result, so it won't work.

I think the way you should probably do this is to construct your input as a batch of batches e.g.

```
intput = tf.placeholder("float", (number_of_batches, batch_size, input_size)
```

Then have your target also be a 3d tensor which can be trained on.